# Is cyclic decomposition of a vector space unique?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, linear-transformations

In my book, it introduces the cyclic decomposition in this way:

$V$ is a $n$ dimentional vector space over a field $F$, $\mathscr{A}$ is a linear transformation. Then:
$$
V=F[\mathscr{A}]\alpha_1\oplus F[\mathscr{A}]\alpha_2 \oplus... \oplus F[\mathscr{A}]\alpha_r
$$
Where $F[\mathscr{A}]\alpha_i\neq0$ for all $i$, and each $\alpha_i$ corresponds to an invariant factor $m_i(\lambda)$, where $m_i(\mathscr{A})\alpha_i=0$. Besides, $m_i(\mathscr{A})$ is the monic polynomial with the least degree to satisfy this. Since the invariant factors of $\mathscr{A}$ are unique, so is this decomposition.

My question is, if we decompose in this way: we choose a nonzero vector $\beta_1$ and we get $F[\mathscr{A}]\beta_1$, then we choose another nonzero $\beta_2\notin F[\mathscr{A}]\beta_1$, and hopefully we get $F[\mathscr{A}]\beta_1 \oplus F[\mathscr{A}]\beta_2$ (I'm not sure whether direct sum or not, or we can intensionally make it direct sum by choosing a "good" $\beta_2$ maybe?). Then we can also get a cyclic decomposition. Is this the same decomposition as the beginning one? Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider a $3$-dimensional cyclic vector space $V$ over $R$, so its cyclic decomposition is :
$$
V=F[\mathscr{A}]\alpha
$$
Thus it must have only one elementary divisor, its Jordan normal form should be:
$$
 \begin{bmatrix}
  \lambda &  &  \\
  1 & \lambda &  \\
   & 1 & \lambda
 \end{bmatrix}
$$
Note that it is the finest decomposition, we cannot decompose it further.

Now consider we happen to take its eigenvector to be $\beta_1$, then $F[\mathscr{A}]\beta_1=k\beta_1$, $k\in F$. Then for any $\beta_2$ that is linear independent with $\beta_1$, we can never have $F[\mathscr{A}]\beta_1\oplus F[\mathscr{A}]\beta_2$, which means the first vector $\beta_1$ cannot be taken just randomly.